# Comma Seperated Values and LIKE php/mysql Troubles

Tags: php, mysql, csv, sql-like

**The Set up**
This is more or less a follow up question to something I had previously posted regarding comma separated values (explode,implode). Here's the scenario which has been stomping me the last few days as I'm a noob--sorry for the lengthy post.

I'm passing a variable via the url (index.php?id=variable), I then check the database to find the rows containing that variable using

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE column LIKE '%$variable%'
```

I'm using the wildcards because the results are a comma separated value with the variable appearing multiple times in the database.

So if we were assigning-- say schools to popular tv shows..my database is set up so that the user can assign more than one school to the tv show.  IE.

South Park--> **fsu**, **nyu** ,**mit**

Archer --> **harvard**, **nyu**

Index.php?id=nyu would display Sourth Park & Archer.

**The Problem**
Because I am using `Like '%variable%'`

If I have the following:
South Park-->**uark**
Archer-->**ua**

index.php?=ua
Instead of just Archer showing, Southpark would also show.

Which makes sense due to the wildcards...but can anyone think of a way to do this achieving the results I want?..Is there any way to achieve more precise results using a comma separated value?..I'm completely stomped and will appreciate any help.

Comment: I don't think this is the best way to use a database. If you have set up proper relationship and not just using the table as storage, this is a trivial problem to solve.

Answer (score 2):

A better option is to create two other tables.
One table is the one you already have 'tv_shows' and the second table is the 'tags' table and the third table is the connection table.

Here is a sample:

```
 CREATE TABLE tags(id INT, tag VARCHAR(200));
 CREATE TABLE tv_tags(show_id INT, tag_id INT);

 SELECT FROM tv_shows,tv_tags WHERE tv_shows.id=tv_tags.show_id AND tag_id IN (SELECT id FROM tags WHERE tag LIKE 'tag');
```

Answer (score 1):

have you tried the REGEXP operator ? sth like

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE column REGEXP('(^|,)%variable%(,|$)')
```

it can be slightly different if you have spaces between your tags, but the idea is here

Comment: Thanks alot, that set me in the right path..I ended using something like this: REGEXP '[[:<:]]".$variable."[[:>:]]'